# Notations in Data Modeling (Crow's Feet etc)

Tags: database-design

What are the standard notations in database modeling. Visio offer two types, The crow feet notations and simple arrows. So which are the industry standards? I am very new in Database modeling and design stuff so please excuse if my question is too dummy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both are standards - for different methodologies.
use whichever one you like best

Comment: You mean they are used in different types of databases? please if you explain a bit the "methodologies point.

Comment: @Zai - no, I mean different design/diagramming methodologies prefer one over the other. For example, James Martin's books use crows' feet, while Yourdon-DeMarco prefers arrows.

Answer (score 1):

The Crow's Feet notation is easier to read in my opinion. It conveys more information pictorially whereas the arrows require extra notations like "1..*" to indicate cardinality. Personally I would also select the IDEF1X table notation option in Visio, which certainly is an industry standard.

As far as I know the "arrows" notation isn't a proper standard at all. In fact I think Microsoft may have invented it - at least I don't recall seeing it anywhere except in their products.